# trigger sql after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

I was trying to create a trigger that after inserts in a table, inserts data on a different table. But shows syntax error, and I do not know where is the error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertDumpData ON users
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO attachments ("1", "sds", "hi");
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh I see you are trying a SQL Server syntax on mySQL.
Try this:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER insertDumpData BEFORE INSERT ON users
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      INSERT INTO attachments values ('1', 'sds', 'hi');
  END;
|
```

Comment: thanks, but the error continues "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON users"

Comment: yes I'm sorry! Now there isn't any errors but the table as zero rows.. and I have tried to insert without the trigger and it works

Comment: on which table? users or attachments ?

Comment: and does it insert data on users?

Comment: yes. table users has a pk email and table attachments has a foreign key email to table users. without the trigger the data is stored in attachment and users, but with the trigger only the table attachment has zero rows.. and I changed "BEFORE INSERT" to "AFTER INSERT"

Comment: very good, if you have a PK from attachments to users you need the row on users first.

Comment: yes and thats what i'm doing. I have an "insert into users" and a trigger "after insert on users".. so when I insert a row in attachment table on trigger action the row with the PK in users is already in the  table users

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget adding a delimiter around the procedure

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER insertDumpData ON users
    ...
    INSERT INTO attachments select "1", "sds", "hi";
    ...
|
```

and as Diego mentioned in his answer: correct your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Missing 'values'

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertDumpData ON users
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO attachments values ("1", "sds", "hi");
END;
```